# how to avoid repeating some elements of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 
CH =
    7    12    31    44    47    49    55    60    75    90
& N is a matrix of 1 and 0

I want to take an element in CH (ex:7) then apply N(7,CH) which means with all the elements of CH except 7 , then I want to move to the second element 12 the check N(12,CH), CH here I want all the elements of CH except 12 & 7. 
Then if N == 1 I want t save the numbers in a matrix. 
This the code that I had tried but the problem that it resulted matrix " one_hop_heads" repeat some result ex: 
one_hop_heads= [7 12 ; 44 49; 12 7] which I dont want such thing
can any one help me?

```
for i=1:length(CH)
          for j=1:length(CH)
              if i~=j
                 if N(CH(i),CH(j))==1
                    one_hop_heads= [one_hop_heads; CH(i),CH(j)];
                 end 
              end 
          end 
    end
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What is the size of N? It would help to have an example of what output you are expecting.

Comment: I've been reading this question for 10 minutes and I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to solve.  Can you please elaborate on what the output should look like?  What exactly do you want to do with `CH` and how does this apply to `N`?

Comment: @rayryeng I'm working under the assumption that `N` is some sort of adjacency matrix and the OP is looking for a list of (undirected) edges. I think Jigg's answer is along the same lines.

Comment: @beaker - Ah, now that makes sense.  Let's see what the OP has to say.   I've refrained from writing an answer as the problem is ill-posed, and the example inputs and outputs don't make sense.  Nice deductions though you and Jigg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you're looking for:

```
for ii=1:length(CH)
    for jj=ii+1:length(CH)
        if N(CH(ii),CH(jj))==1
            one_hop_heads= [one_hop_heads; CH(ii),CH(jj)];
        end 
    end 
end
```

(Note that I've changed the variables `i` and `j` to `ii` and `jj` so as to avoid conflict with the built-in imaginary numbers.)

What this does:
Each loop over `jj` starts at `ii+1`. This ensures that `ii` is is always strictly less than `jj` (which removes one `if` statement). By using ordered pairs in this way, you ensure that if you look at a pair `(ii, jj)`, you will never look at the pair `(jj, ii)`.

I believe you could also do this without the loop by using `find`, similar to Jigg's answer:

```
N2 = triu(N(CH,CH),1);
[ii,jj] = find(N2);
one_hop_heads = [CH(ii),CH(jj)];
```

**Note:** Both of these solutions assume `N` is symmetric. If this is not the case, you'll have to clarify what the structure of `N` is and I can adjust the solutions.